# set time count down

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk

I would like to set time count down, using `NSTimer` like start with 20 minutes then elapsed 19 min.,18 min etc. (only minutes not seconds) this elapsed time show in text file, Please help.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What has been tried? Did it work correctly? If not, why not?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will want to create a timer that looks like this:

```
NSTimer *myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60 target: self selector:@selector(time:) userInfo: nil repeats: true];
//the timer takes seconds, so by feeding it 60, it will tick every minute
```

Then your `time:` function will have to look like this:

```
- (void)time:(NSTimer *)timerObject{
    //do whatever needs to be done every minute, like updating your UI
    //and subtracting from your counter variable
}
```

(you do not have to use timerObject)